# How to get Windows NT version via command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, shortcuts, user-agent

Many times I have to pass the User-Agent in the download headers for the download to be validated and working.

I need help finding a easy method to get the Windows NT version`(6.1 or 6.2 ....)` which the current running **Windows** system is (Win7, Win8, Win10 etc.) including **Windows Server** OSes?

I searched a lot in Google, but cannot find a specific command or shortcut for getting that info.

Comment: See the list:: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions

Comment: From an elevated command prompt, you can get this information by typing in `wmic os get version` and pressing Enter

Comment: I suppose your command returns the Windows OS build and not the NT version, please check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions as there are differences between those two versions before Windows 10

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but this will show the same information as typing `ver` in the command line including the NT version and the OS build number. For example `10.0.15063` would mean NT version 10.0 for the NT portion and the `15063` would indicate the OS build. Your question says how to get ***how to get the Windows NT version*** and this gets just that information you requested.

Comment: Ok let me check on the other system with Windows 7.

Comment: Yes it works on Windows 7 and Windows 8, sorry to doubt that, please write this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry, just seeing the comment, please see my answer below and let me know if I should add anything further that you feel would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) command in a syntax of `wmic os get version` to return the NT version number and the OS build number—use an administrator elevated command prompt if needed.

You can also use the [ver](https://ss64.com/nt/ver.html) command in a syntax of `ver` to return the NT version number and the OS build number from command line too—use an administrator elevated command prompt if needed.

> ### Command Line Example
>
> ## **`wmic os get version`**
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> ### **`ver`**
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> - *The **OS Version Number** is the `10.0` portion—everything behind the second dot*
> - *The **OS Build Number** is the `15063` value portion—everything in front of the second dot*

---

### Further Resources

- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)
- [ver](https://ss64.com/nt/ver.html)

> ### [Windows OS Version Number Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx)
>
> [image]

---

> ### [Windows 10 release information](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx)
>
> Microsoft has updated its servicing model. The Semi-Annual Channel is
>   a twice-per-year feature update release targeting March and September,
>   and 18-month servicing timelines for each release. The Semi-Annual
>   Channel replaces the Current Branch (CB) and Current Branch for
>   Business (CBB) concepts starting July 2017 with Windows 10, version
>   1703. This page is designed to help you determine if your devices are up to date with the latest Windows 10 feature and quality updates and
>   to plan deployment schedules.
>
> With each Semi-Annual Channel release, we recommend beginning
>   deployment right away to targeted devices and ramp up to full
>   deployment at your discretion. This will enable you to gain access to
>   new features, experiences, and integrated security as soon as
>   possible. For more information, see the [blog
>   post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsitpro/2017/07/27/waas-simplified-and-aligned/)
>   and [Quick guide to Windows as a
>   service](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/deployment/update/waas-quick-start).
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

`systeminfo` is probably the command you want.  It does tend to spit out a lot of information, so you can run

```
systeminfo | find /i "OS Version"
```

to get just the item you need.